# How to translate this code from Windows Form to WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

http://www.gutgames.com/post/Adjusting-Brightness-of-an-Image-in-C.aspx

Can anybody help me please?

The graphics class does not work in WPF

Comment: Give it a try first and post specific questions here.

Comment: This does not even have anything to do with WinForms...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be changed.  Use an Image element, set the source in code to the resulting bitmap type.

Comment: The graphics thing does not work in WPF